# What is pronunciation of Efron in American and british English?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm reading Statistics. there is a statistician named [Bradly Efron](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~ckirby/brad/) which I have doubt in pronunciation of his name. Firstly I readed his name: `ɛfrɒn` but google translate reads it: `ɛfron`.

Which one on correct?

Comment: **PRO TIP**: Almost all "which one is correct?" questions about language have a hidden assumption built right into them that is false right off the bat.

Comment: In the US "Efron" would almost always be pronounced "eff-ron", "eff-run", or "eff-ren".

Comment: @HotLicks That is meaningless mumbo jumbo that nobody will know how to say. YOU CANNOT REPRESENT ENGLISH PRONUNCIATION USING ENGLISH LETTERS! *Especially* to an international audience of learners. You have to use IPA: look whom you're addressing for the love of Somebody!

Comment: I will start using IPA when someone can demonstrate that it works.  I've seen no evidence of this, just a lot of smoke and mirrors.

Comment: according to wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradley_Efron, it's `ɛfrən`

Comment: @HotLicks what's the big difference between "eff-run" and `ɛfrʌn`? in both of them you refer to the same vowels, while using a different writing system. there's practically no functional difference. with IPA, non-native speakers can at least go to wikipedia and hear how the vowel really sounds like. I can tell you that at least for my Israeli colleagues, writing "eff-run" can only cause them to pronounce it as `e̞frän`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your suggested pronunciations are wrong, even if he were Scottish. It could never be an [r] for one thing, nor could it be a full [o] in an unstressed syllable. And being that he’s at Stanford, he probably can’t see [ɒ] as a phoneme, since it isn’t one in General American.

Any and all of [ˈɛfɹɔn], [ˈɛfɹɒn], [ˈɛfɹɑn], [ˈɛfɹɨn], [ˈɛfɹən], and [ˈɛfɹn̩] are perfectly plausible, but there’s simply no way to know without asking the gentleman yourself. And even he may not be self-consistent.

But seriously, it doesn’t matter. Just pronounce it the normal way that the phonology leads you to, whichever one of those I’ve listed up there makes sense in your own accent. Nobody will not know whom you’re referring to.

Just don’t say it either of your two ways. Those are both wrong.

Comment: Actually, considering Efron’s a statistician, I’m fairly sure quite a lot of people will not know who’s being referred to, entirely regardless of how SirSaleh pronounces the name. (And of course both variants given in the question are perfectly fine if they’re _phonemic_ writing, one being BrE, the other AmE, though of a non-existent pronunciation.)